# Can a person who is under a Nazarite Vow, keep Pesach?

Tags: passover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nozir and four cups of wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/nozir-and-four-cups-of-wine)

Is it possible to continue a Nazarite vow and still participate in Passover?

Comment: Don W, welcome to Judaism.SE and thanks for your question! As you can see, it has been asked elsewhere using slightly different wording. Please feel free to add to the discussion there, or repost a specific question if you feel yours is not satisfactorily addressed by the existing material. I hope to see you around the site!

Comment: Don, I'll just add that it's still of great value to the Internet to have an additional path to the question and answers in your words, so people who use similar words to search will find the content. Also, if you do want to add aspects to this question that were not addressed in the Four Cups question, feel free to use the [edit] function.