# Can a Nazir drink wine if it is part of a holiday observance?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, grapes-wine, nozir

One who takes a Nazarite vow cannot drink wine (or partake of product that uses grapes). I understand that this is to help the Nazir remain focused on God instead of being overcome by other forces (such as being drunk and doing whatever drunkenness entails, i.e., losing inhibitions, not thinking before acting, etc.).
As a Jew though, can a Nazir drink wine if it is for ritual purposes and not solely personal enjoyment? For example, what comes to mind is wine that is a part of the Passover meal, and also Kiddush.

(*Side note*: I'm not sure if wine was part of Pesach in the Torah, perhaps it was instituted by Rabbis post-Torah? Perhaps all the incorporations of wine were instituted post-Torah by the Rabbis?)

Comment: You can find answers to part of this here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/nozir-and-four-cups-of-wine

Comment: @IsaacMoses, not a duplicate?

Comment: Nazir 3b and on

Comment: Clearly this is a partial duplicate, but it is the more general and better question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Yerushalmi Nazir 6:5 and Bavli Nasir 3b (thanks DoubleAA) quote the opinion of R' Yossi HaGelili that a Nazir may not drink Ma'aser Sheini wine. He derives this from Bamidbar 6:3, which says both "wine" and "strong drink," which he finds repetitious (as wine *is* a strong drink). He therefore learns that the repetition is "to make wine for a Mitzvah like optional wine." So, no, a Nazir would not be able to have four cups of wine. He would be able to have four cups of a *chamar medinah*, though, [as Alex noted in this question that asks specifically about Arba Kosos.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8149/9682)

Comment: see also machloket Rashi Rsbenu Tam about this

Comment: Do we rule like R Yossi HaGelili?

Answer (score 1):

the Nazir may not drink wine, because he is observing the commandments of the Torah, De Orayata. While drinking 4 cups of wine, kiddush and HavDalla is Rabbinical, De Rabanan.

Comment: A source would greatly improve this answer

Comment: 10 mitvoth of Nazirut, could be found in Parahsat Naso ( De Oraita)

Comment: Great. As a rule, it is always better to edit any additions directly into your answer (press edit below the answer). Comments are temporary in nature and often get deleted over time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We hope you stay around. As mbloch mentioned, you can improve your answer by editing in more details or sources. Looking forward to hearing more from you.