# Wrong ברכת הנהנין during הבדלה: what now?

Tags: blessing, food, mistakes, havdalah

This evening (after *Shabas* in [the nine days](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Days)), I recited *havdala* over a cup of beer, as every year. I knew it was beer, but, by force of habit, recited "*hagafen*" (the wine benediction) over it during *havdala*. I continued, reciting the (correct!) benedictions over the spices and fire, and then began the final, *havdala* benediction, during which I realized my error.

Not knowing what to do, I completed *havdala*, sat down, recited "*shehakol*" (the beer benediction), and drank. What *should* I have done? (There are multiple issues here: Do I drink the beer? If so, do I first say *shehakol*? And do I have to repeat *havdala*?)

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%98

Comment: @msh210 Besamim and Ner can be said by themselves (as will be done this coming week), so you are certainly Yotzei on that front.

Comment: There is the opinion of R' Yehoshua ben Chananya ([*P'sachim* 103a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=103&format=text)) that the *hagafen* can follow the *havdala* blessing (he says to do נהי"ק instead of יקנה"ז), and perhaps we follow the underlying principle that the order is not *m'akeiv b'di'avad*. | Also, since this comment disappeared, I'll reiterate that the *MB* says that the *Shulchan Aruch* there (*s'if* 1) is overwhelmingly rejected by most *poskim*, and that the *hagafen* would not count for the beer. @DoubleAA

Comment: @Fred There is further indication that by Kiddush at least the order of the blessings is not _meakeiv_ eg. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%98%D7%95 Indeed it's not clear why it would be.

Comment: @DoubleAA Relatedly, see the dispute between Beis Hillel and Beis Shamai in the mishna on [*P'sachim* 114a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=114&format=text) about the order in kiddush.

Comment: Not [orange juice](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/drinking-havdalah-wine-during-the-9-days#comment12548_4852)? :)

Comment: @Fred Truth is, I usually say it on OJ. When I wrote "as every year" in this question, I was referring to my use of _chamar m'dina_, not to my use of beer.

Comment: @Fred Yes, but I was speaking _lehalacha_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Riv'vos Efrayim*, volume 2, responsum 115, paragraph 57 (on page 200)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&pgnum=200), in part, in my own, loose translation:

> It seems that if he did not recite "*hagafen*" in *havdala* he fulfills his obligation. However, if he remembers before the drinking of the wine, he must then recite "*hagafen*".

My omitting "*shehakol*", the correct benediction, on my beer is akin, as far as I can tell, to the case in the *Riv'vos Efrayim*. Thus, I fulfilled my *havdala* obligation and I was correct to recite "*shehakol*" after *havdala* and drink the beer. (My extra "*hagafen*" was *l'vatala*, in vain, but I don't see why that would affect the issue of whether I fulfilled my *havdala* obligation or the issue of what to do about the "*shehakol*" and the beer.)

Answer (score -2):

You did the right thing. Also good to say Baruch sheim kevod... after drinking the beer since you made a bracha l'vatala.

Comment: Citing support for your claims would improve your answer immensely.